# JSF 2.2 and Flows - Unable to find matching navigation case from view ID

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, flow-scope

I develop a simple JSF flow application. JSF.2.2 and GlassFish 4.

View structure of application looks like:
[image]

But problem appears, when I enter to some flow. For example FLOW-A. After that, I get following warning:

```
Unable to find matching navigation case from view ID '/faces/views/metadata/overview.xhtml' for outcome 'flow-a'
```

[image]

I can't go again to the same flow when I already in this flow?

Comment: Have you found solution ?